# WP7 - How do i add tiles to my app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, addition, tiles

Basically, I'm almost finished making this note app which the users save notes etc. Basic note app function. The reason I'm not fully done is that i just need help with adding tiles to my app for the notes. Basically the user clicks the "Pin to start" from the menu item and for the selected note, pins that to the start. I've done this through:

```
 Private Sub PinToStart_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim Storage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim data As SampleData = TryCast(TryCast(sender, MenuItem).DataContext, SampleData)
    Dim selectedItem As ListBoxItem = TryCast(Me.SavedNotesList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data), ListBoxItem)
    Dim directory As String = "./MyNote/SavedNotes/*.*"
    Dim filenames As String() = Storage.GetFileNames(directory)
    Dim dataSource As New List(Of SampleData)()
    For Each filename As String In filenames
        Dim ISF As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
        Dim FS As IsolatedStorageFileStream = ISF.OpenFile("MyNote/SavedNotes/" & filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim FETime As String = Storage.GetCreationTime("MyNote/SavedNotes/" & data.FileNameX).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy h:mmtt")
        Dim tileData As New StandardTileData() With { _
             .Title = data.FileNameX, _
             .BackgroundImage = New Uri("/Assets/202.png", UriKind.Relative), _
             .BackTitle = data.FileNameX, _
             .BackContent = data.Description}
        ShellTile.Create(New Uri("/ViewPage.xaml?Title=" & data.FileNameX & "&Body=" & data.Description, UriKind.Relative), tileData)
    Next
End Sub
```

Currently this is the code which creates the tile. Although there is one problem, once the tile is created it throws an exception and says "Tiles can only be created when the application is in the foreground" but it still proceeds and creates the tile with no problem. Second error i have is that I need a way to update the tile. I just don't know how.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

use HubTile control from Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit to created tile
 you can try this code:
    var shellTileData = new StandardTileData 
                {
                    BackgroundImage = new Uri("Path for image", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                   BackContent = "xyz"

```
            };
            var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
            tile.Update(shellTileData);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that but what about updating the tile? how can i do that?

Comment: have you got solution??

Comment: Hey I've added the code, I tried to debug it but I got an error. It highlights HubTile.Name, Hubtile.Title and Hubtile.Message. Says "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." Any idead how i can fix this ?

Comment: are you using hubtile control in xaml part?

Comment: Nop. I'm using the default StandardTileData